# Is there a log of the output of startup commands?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, init.rc

While Ubuntu is starting up, the init rc commands are run.
Is there a way to see their full output after the system has started?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `dmesg` or the contents of `/var/syslog`?

Comment: Both `dmesg` and `/var/syslog` have syslog-generate comment, and not the output upon initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu stores the output of the rc commands run at boot in `/var/log/boot.log`.

Comment: `/var/log/boot.log` is exactly what I was looking for! That doesn't go through syslog, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't use syslog. `/var/log/boot.log` is created by [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth).

Answer (score 0):

The default system log location in Ubuntu 13.04 is `/var/log/syslog`.

Log location settings are configured in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

See `man rsyslog.conf` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[`dmesg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dmesg.1.html) is a ring buffer, so it can be that messages from the top can be overwritten by newer messages, although at 16384 messages I doubt it.

Have you tried `/var/log/boot.log` or `/var/log/kernel.log`